# Are achievements available for PC version of LEGO Star Wars: The Complete Saga?

Tags: xbox-network, games-for-windows-live, lego-star-wars

I am looking to find out if there are Xbox Live (or Games for Windows Live) achievements for the PC version of LEGO Star Wars: The Complete Saga.

Specifically, I'm interested in buying a copy of this game on Steam, but I can't find out if the [achievements](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/lego-star-wars-the-complete-saga/guide/) available for the XBox 360 version are also available for the PC version.

Searching for this game on the [Games for Windows](http://www.gamesforwindows.com/en-US/) website doesn't return any hit. Does this mean the achievements are not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, there are no Live achievements available for the PC version, only the games listed underneath their catalog as [LIVE enabled](http://www.gamesforwindows.com/en-US/Games/?filter=LIVE+Enabled&order=Title&ascending=True&type=All#filterGroup) have achievements associated with them. You can also see a list of PC games with achievements at [xbox360achievements.org](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/games/pc/) which matches up with the Games for Windows catalog.

Answer (score 0):

You can usually tell by the case of the game. If its just games for windows then there are no achievements for it. If its games for windows LIVE then yes, it will have achievements.

Comment: As stated in the question, I would buy the game on Steam, so there's no case. I also could not find any mention of "Game for Windows" on the Steam description.